# Recycle bitmaps made with createScaledBitmap

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, out-of-memory, scale

I wrote an example code to generically show my issue.

Basically, inside the onDraw of a View, I want to create a scaled up bitmap, draw it on canvas, recyle that bitmap and free its memory, and do it again and again, in a loop.

The problem is that memory grows and grows at each step of the loop, and remains full even after that onDraw has finished, even after waiting some time.

As far as my logic goes, canvas already contains a bitmap sized like the screen, so it should not grow in memory size whatever I draw into it, and I suppose each of the scaled up bitmaps remains in memory even though i called recycle on them and even though their reference is destroyed.

Where am I wrong?
Thanks!

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

    int i=0;
    while(i<10) {

        matrix = new Matrix();

        bitmapToDraw = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), false);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapToDraw, matrix, imagePaintF);
        bitmapToDraw.recycle();
        bitmapToDraw = null;

        i++;
    }

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Just by repeating the loop 10 times, memory grows to -and always remains at- almost 200MB.
If I do it more and more, it goes outOfMemory. While by recycling bitmaps, I should be able to do it without a limit.

Comment: what do you need `createScaledBitmap` for? you are drawing the bitmap with `Matrix` parameter after all...

Comment: Please don't focus on what I use it for, this is just an example with no meaning.

Comment: Did you get OutOfMemoryException for this case?

Comment: @Twinsens Yes, by repeating the loop enough times, I get OutOfMemoryException. With every step of the loop, memory grows and is never freed.

Comment: what does `getLayerType` return? is it hardware?

Comment: @pskink I'm not familiar with getLayerType so I don't know if I got it right but, by executing it at the start of onDraw, it returns 0 (LAYER_TYPE_NONE)

Comment: and if you use the off-screen canvas (for example `new Canvas(offScreenTemporaryBitmap)`), does it work the same?

Comment: @pskink It... works. I tried drawing all the bitmaps on a different Canvas object, and then drawing that canvas's inner bitmap on the main onDraw Canvas, and it seems to work like I intended now. I still have to try in my actual program but wow great. I'd very much like to know the reason.

Comment: ok now use the "normal" canvas (the one that is passed to `onDraw` method) but try to change layer type: try both software and hardware, change it in your custom view constructor

Comment: @pskink Software keeps memory under control, while Hardware crashes like the previous one. But with both, it doesn't seem to draw anything on screen.

Comment: with software you see nothing ? what about simplest `canvas.drawColor(Color.RED)`? just black screen?

Comment: also for testing, try disabling it on activity level: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#controlling

Comment: @pskink drawColor worked, but the drawBitmap of my scaled bitmaps didn't have any effect. But now, by putting hardwareAccelerated="false" in the manifest activity, drawBitmap works again.

Comment: strange, really strange...

Comment: @pskink The whole view code if needed https://pastebin.com/tcmGewJ7

Comment: just use `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);` BTW what is the canvas passed to `onDraw` method? `Log.d(TAG, "canvas: " + canvas.getClass())` run the code twice, with and without `setLayerType`

Comment: @pskink Yeah I actually tried with null too. Still no effect on screen unless hardware acceleration is disabled in manifest. - With hw acceleration disabled in manifest, it says in both cases 'android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas', but by removing that part from the manifest, it says android.view.DisplayListCanvas without setLayer, and android.graphics.Canvas with it.

Comment: again strange that you had to call `new Paint()`... hmmm... so at the end did you change anything in the manifest? or just `setLayerType` made a trick?

Comment: @pskink Yes I repeat, with setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null), drawBitmap only works if hardwareAccelerated="false" is also set. About that the question is now: is it ok if I do that on release? Since you said to do it just for testing.

Comment: honestly it looks suspicious...  try reading https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html and play a bit with the settings: it shouldnt be done in both places imho (manifest and `setLayerType`) - it smells fishy...

Comment: @pskink Ok, thanks anyway for all the suggestions. Could it be better to use that temporary offscreen canvas instead?

Comment: no, i dont think so - it should be done directly, without any offscreen bitmap/canvas

Comment: @pskink Back on my original program, seems like just putting setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null) in my view constructors worked.

Comment: this is what I suggested from the beginning.... now it looks more normal